# Ask for a generating function or an explicit expression of a triangle of positive integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-number-theory, generating-functions, integer-sequences, hypergeometric-functions

**Preliminaries**

I encountered the following triangle of positive integers:

| $c_{n,k}$ | $n=1$ | $n=2$ | $n=3$ | $n=4$ | $n=5$ | $n=6$ | $n=7$ | $n=8$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $k=0$ | $1$ | $3$ | $15$ | $105$ | $315$ | $3465$ | $45045$ | $45045$ |
| $k=1$ |  | $5$ | $40$ | $385$ | $1470$ | $19635$ | $300300$ | $345345$ |
| $k=2$ |  |  | $33$ | $511$ | $2688$ | $45738$ | $849849$ | $1150149$ |
| $k=3$ |  |  |  | $279$ | $2370$ | $55638$ | $1317888$ | $2167737$ |
| $k=4$ |  |  |  |  | $965$ | $36685$ | $1200199$ | $2518087$ |
| $k=5$ |  |  |  |  |  | $11895$ | $631540$ | $1831739$ |
| $k=6$ |  |  |  |  |  |  | $169995$ | $801535$ |
| $k=7$ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | $184331$ |

The first row $c_{n,0}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$ is perhaps the sequence at https://oeis.org/A025547. The other positive integers $c_{n,k}$ are defined as follows.

Let $C_{n,k}=\frac{c_{n,k}}{c_{n,0}}$ for $0\le k\le n-1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. These real numbers $C_{n,k}$ satisfy
$$
C_{n,0}=1, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
and the following recurrent relations
\begin{gather}
C_{n+2,1}-C_{n+1,1}=1, \\
(2n+3)(C_{n+2,n+1}-C_{n+1,n})=2(n+1)(C_{n+1,n}-C_{n,n-1}), \\
(2n+3)(C_{n+2,k}-C_{n+1,k}-C_{n+1,k-1})
=2(n+1)(C_{n+1,k-1}-C_{n,k-1}-C_{n,k-2}). \label{recur-c-C(n-k)-Four} \tag{PQ}
\end{gather}

It is not difficult to obtain
\begin{gather}
C_{n,1}=\frac{3n-1}{3}, \quad n\ge2,\label{C(n1)}\tag{PQ1}\\
C_{n,2}=\frac{15 n^2-25 n+6}{30}, \quad n\ge3,\label{C(n2)}\tag{PQ2}\\
C_{n,3}=\frac{35n^3-140n^2+147n-30}{210}, \quad n\ge4,\label{C(n3)}\tag{PQ3}
\end{gather}
and
\begin{equation}\label{C(n+1:n)-Explicit}\tag{PQ4}
C_{n+1,n}=\frac{2n+3}{2}B\biggl(\frac{1}{2},n+2\biggr)-1
=\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+1)!!}-1, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,\dotsc\}.
\end{equation}
where $B(\alpha,\beta)$ denotes the classical beta function. Therefore, by virtue of the formulas \eqref{C(n1)} and \eqref{C(n2)}, the recurrent relation \eqref{recur-c-C(n-k)-Four} can be inductively and recursively transformed to
\begin{equation}\label{Similar-Pascal-Rul}\tag{PR}
C_{n+2,k}=C_{n+1,k}+C_{n+1,k-1}, \quad 1\le k\le n.
\end{equation}

**Two Problems**

(1) Can one find an explicit expression of the sequence $c_{n,k}$ for $0\le k\le n-1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

(2) What is the generating function of the sequence $c_{n,k}$ for $0\le k\le n-1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

**About Pascal's rule**

It is common knowledge that the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ satisfy Pascal's rule
\begin{equation}
\binom{n+2}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k-1}.
\end{equation}
This means that the sequence of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ is a solution to the recurrent relation \eqref{Similar-Pascal-Rul}.

As Alexander Burstein commented below, another solution to the recurrent relation \eqref{Similar-Pascal-Rul}, satisfying \eqref{C(n1)}, \eqref{C(n2)}, \eqref{C(n3)}, and \eqref{C(n+1:n)-Explicit}, is
\begin{equation}\label{AB-Seq}\tag{AB}
C_{n,k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}\binom{n}{k-j}, \quad 0\le k\le n-1.
\end{equation}

**One more problem**

Except the sequence of the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ and the sequence in \eqref{AB-Seq}, are there any more solutions to the recurrent relation \eqref{Similar-Pascal-Rul}?

**Alternative form of $C_{n,k}$**

Similar to \eqref{C(n+1:n)-Explicit}, the following expressions are also valid:
\begin{align}
C_{n+2,n}&=\frac{1}{3}\frac{(2n+4)!!}{(2n+1)!!}-\frac{3n+5}{3}, \label{C(n+2+n)-Explicit}\tag{PQ5}\\
C_{n+3,n}
&=\frac{1}{15}\frac{(2n+6)!!}{(2n+1)!!}-\frac{15 n^2+65 n+66}{30}, \label{C(n+3:n)-Explicit}\tag{PQ6}\\
C_{n+4,n}
&=\frac{1}{105}\frac{(2n+8)!!}{(2n+1)!!} -\frac{35 n^3+280 n^2+707 n+558}{210} \label{C(n+4:n)-Form}\tag{PQ7}
\end{align}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. I guess that
\begin{equation}\label{beta(m-j)}\tag{PQ8}
C_{n+m,n}=\frac{1}{(2m-1)!!} \frac{(2n+2m)!!}{(2n+1)!!}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\beta_{m,j}n^j, \quad m,n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
What is the explicit or closed-form expression of $\beta_{m,j}$ in \eqref{beta(m-j)} for $0\le j\le m-1$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The first row is the sequence at https://oeis.org/A025547

Comment: I think it will not help to just post some numbers without giving the method / definition how you compute those numbers.

Comment: Looks like the main diagonal is [A129890](http://oeis.org/A129890)(n)/[A025549](http://oeis.org/A025549)(n).

Comment: And the alternating sums of columns look like [A000165](https://oeis.org/A000165)(n)/[A025549](http://oeis.org/A025549)(n). Of course, there is no way to be sure without knowing how the entire triangle is generated.

Comment: This should be closed if an explanation is not provided soon.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein You are greater!!! It is very useful, applicable, important, novel, and innovative in mathematics to guess the general term of a sequence from a part of its terms. I believe that your observations are intrinsic and important for my research.

Comment: From your formulas, it looks like $$C_{n,k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}\binom{n}{k-j}.$$

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein
You are the really greatest man! I believe that your formula is fully right. For saving my time, could you please write down your proof of this formula and post your proof as an answer here? Could you please e-mail your proof to me? My e-mail address is honest.john.china@gmail.com. Anyway, you have succeeded a great stride! Thank you very much, Dr. Alexander Burstein.

Comment: @qifeng618 In the general case, I think most of the verification is just collecting terms at each factor of $(-1)^j/(2j+1)$ and using the binomial formula. The boundary cases are also routine to verify.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein After you wrote down your formula, it may be not difficult to verify it. However, before your wrote out your formula, it should be not easy to find out the solution. How did you discover your formula? I think the arguments and thoughts you wrote your formula are more interesting.

Comment: @qifeng618 I wrote the formulas PQ1, PQ2, PQ3 as a linear combination of binomial coefficients, noticed a pattern, and wrote down the conjecture. It was a lucky guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generating function:
$${\cal C}(x,y) = \sum_{n,k\geq 0} C_{n,k} x^n y^{2k}$$
has the following explicit form:
$${\cal C}(x,y) = \frac{\arctan(y)}{y(1-x(1+y^2))}.$$

For "one more problem", you may like to check a [paper on the Graham–Knuth–Patashnik recurrence](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v28i2p18).

**UPDATED**. Finally, we get the following formula for the coefficicnets $\beta_{m,t}$ in the formula for $C_{n+m,n}$:
$$\beta_{m,t} = \sum_{j=t}^{m-1} \frac{(-1)^{j+m}}{(2(j-m)+1)\cdot j!}\sum_{\ell=t}^{j} s(j,\ell) \binom{\ell}{t} m^{\ell-t},$$
where $s(\cdot,\cdot)$ are [Stirling numbers of 1st kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Dear Max, using Mathematica 12, I tried to numerically verify your formula $$\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)(m+j)!}\sum_{\ell=t}^{m+j} s(m+j,\ell) \binom{\ell}{t} m^{\ell-t},$$ but found it seemingly wrong.

Comment: @qifeng618: please elaborate on what you think is wrong.

Comment: Dear Max, I substituted your formula into (PQ8) and took $m=1,2,3,4$, but I didn’t obtained (PQ4) to (PQ7).

Comment: The quantity $\beta_{m,j}$ should be independent of $n$, but your formula contains $n$ as a limit of a sum.

Comment: Even if replacing $n$ by $m$, the expression $$\beta_{m,j}=\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)(m+j)!}\sum_{\ell=t}^{m+j} s(m+j,\ell) \binom{\ell}{t} m^{\ell-t}$$ is not valid yet. But I think it would be correct after some minor modifications.

Comment: @qifeng618: Yes, it was my mistake. The formula for $\beta$ is now corrected.